# using LibVLCSharp on asp.net core razor page

Tags: razor-pages, libvlcsharp

Ho we use LibVLCSharp on an Asp.net core razor page ?

I have looked at the LibVLCSharp.NetCore.Sample sample, which is an asp.net core console app
i tried to crate an asp.net core webapplication and try to modify the example to display the video 
on the razor page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking is to have a VLC based player in the browser, this will be supported when https://code.videolan.org/jbk/vlc.js/ lands.

If what you are asking is use LibVLCSharp on the server to stream to a JS player in a webpage, it is likely possible (though probably not the best tool for the job), but you will have to edit your question with more details as to what you want to know.

Comment: i am looking to have VLC based player in browser.

Comment: then it is unrelated to Razor/ASP.NET or any backend tech

Answer (score 0):

The LibVLCSharp.NetCore.Sample is a .net core sample, not an ASP.net core sample.

Displaying a video in a web page is something that goes beyond the usage of libvlc.

See also [this issue](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/257)